# Scrape data from HTML pages with sequenced span IDs using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working with certain HTML pages from which I need to scrape data. The issue is that span ids are numbered. 
For example -

```
ContentPlaceHolder_0, ContentPlaceHolder_1, ContentPlaceHolder_2 ..... ContentPlaceHolder_n
```

I need to get data from all of these span tags at each page. What would be the best approach to get this data using Beautiful Soup?

Comment: try this selector `[id^=ContentPlaceHolder_]`

Answer (score 2):

You can try CSS selectors built-in within BeautifulSoup. This will select all span whose ids are beginning with `ContentPlaceHolder`:

```
soup.select('span[id^=ContentPlaceHolder]')
```

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<span id='ContentPlaceHolder_0'>0</span>
<span id='ContentPlaceHolder_1'>1</span>
<span id='ContentPlaceHolder_2'>2</span>
<span id='ContentPlaceHolder_3'>3</span>

<span id='xxx'>xxx</span>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for s in soup.select('span[id^=ContentPlaceHolder]'):
    print(s.text)
```

Prints:

```
0
1
2
3
```